# How do I solve a problem installing tidyverse

Tags: r

I have some troubles calling tidyverse in R Studio. When I try to load the library for tidyverse I get the following message:

```
install.packages("tidyverse") 

library(tidyverse)

Error in gzfile(file, "rb") : cannot open the connection
In addition: Warning message:
In gzfile(file, "rb") :
  cannot open compressed file 'C:/Users/user/Documents/R/win-library/3.5/generics/R/generics.rdx', probable reason 'No such file or directory'
Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘tidyverse’:
 unable to load R code in package ‘generics’
```

I've tried to uninstall and reinstalling R Studio but it didn't fix the problem. I also do some research on the web but I couldn't find something to solve this question.

Thanks!

Comment: Did `tidyverse` install properly or did it have a non-zero exit status?

Comment: What happens when you try to install `generics`?